# Entity Framework Migrations: Pending migration after "update-database"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, npgsql

I'm using entity framework version 6.1.3 and .NET Framework 4.0.

I'm trying to use Migrations from Code-First from existing Database.
I'm having a trouble that whenever I use the `Update-Database` it makes the changes from my migration, and changes my database, but it keeps the migration as "Pending" and when I try to add another migration with `Add-Migration`, it says I have pending migration.

Example of the problem:

1. Run the `Enable-Migrations` command from the Package Manager Console.
2. Run the `Add-Migration first` command to create an initial migration.
3. Remove all the code in Up() method for the initial migration, because I don't want to create the tables that already exists.
4. Run the `Update-Database` command to apply the initial migration to my database (it runs successfully).
5. Make changes to my code-first model (add column to existing table).
6. Run the `Add-Migration second` command to create a new migration.

When I run step 6, I get the following error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201601111013546_first]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

If I delete the migration "[201601111013546_first]" from my Migrations folder, I can run step 6, and use the `Update-Database`, and it successfully changes my database, adding the column I wanted, but if I change my model again and use `Add-Migration third`, it says the same error, that the second migration is still pending.

Also, if instead of steps 5 and 6, I just run `Update-Database` again, it runs the same script returning the obvious error of already having a 'MigrationId' in the table dbo."__MigrationHistory":

> ERROR: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory"

I already tried:

- Create a new project (ConsoleApplication) and made the same steps getting the same errors.
- Delete entire Migration folder and run `Enable-Migrations` again.
- Verify the namespace of the Migration and it's .Designer file.
- I have only one connectionString but still tried the commands with `-ConnectionStringName`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Use Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges to take an initial snapshot of your database, although commenting out the Up() code should have the same net effect. After update-database, make sure a __MigrationHistory has the record in it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1

Comment: Hello Steve, i tried to create the migration with the "-IgnoreChanges" and made the other steps, but still got the same error. I also checked my __MigrationHistory table and it has the record of the migration.

Comment: Is this SQL Server, localdb or other? Is EF in your web project or separate?

Comment: I'm using npgSQL, and I created a localhost db. Yes, EF is in my web project, and I have only this project in the solution. 
And i just followed the entire step-by-step video in your link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx but still got the same error.

Comment: OK, that's a horse of a different color. Does npgsql even support migrations? http://vincechan.me/tag/npgsql/

Comment: Oh, well... That kind of answer the problem.. If you answer this below i can mark the post as answered and upvote.Thank you very much Steve.

Comment: Not really an answer. You might find better help if you repost in npgsql areas.